# Change paragraph after selecting value in dropbox in js

Tags: javascript, select

I have a form with dropbox with a few options.
I want to change a paragraph according to the selected value in the dropbox, i.e. the selected value will replace the paragraph.
For ex. I have:

```
<select name="howmanyno1" size=1>
<option value=2 selected>2</option>
<option value=3>3</option>
<option value=4>4</option>
<option value=5>5</option>
</select>
//somewhere below
<p>number</p>`
```

I need the text "number" be replaced after selecting a value from the dropbox, with the value selected (2,3,4 or 5).
How should I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select onchange="myFunction()" name="howmanyno1" id="mySelect">
<option value=2 selected>2</option>
<option value=3>3</option>
<option value=4>4</option>
<option value=5>5</option>
</select>

<p id="demo">number</p>`

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="howmanyno1" id="selectDiv" size=1 onchange="changePara()">
<option value=2 selected>2</option>
<option value=3>3</option>
<option value=4>4</option>
<option value=5>5</option>
</select>
//somewhere below
<p id="changed">number</p>
```

**js code**

```
function changePara(){
    var val = document.getElementById("selectDiv").value;
    if(val == 2){
          document.getElementById("changed").innerHTML = "something";
    }
    else if(val == 3){
          document.getElementById("changed").innerHTML = "something else";
    }
    // and so on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## A jQuery based solution

Add an `id` to your `<p>` element

```
<p id="para">number</p>
```

Use jQuery to select the `<select>` box

```
let select = $('select[name="howmanyno1"]')
```

Create a function for updating the text in `<p>`

```
let updateText = function(e) {
    $('#para').text("Selected item: " + select.val())
}
```

And then make the `select` box listen to the `change` event

```
select.on('change', updateText)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solution will be usefull

```js
var textBlocks = new Array( 
'Select from the list to change this box', 
'Text block two', 
'Text block three');

function changeText(elemid) { 
var ind = document.getElementById(elemid).selectedIndex; 
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=textBlocks[ind]; 
}
```

```html
</head><body>


<select id="dropDown" onChange="changeText('dropDown');"> 
<option value="0">1</option> 
<option value="1">2</option> 
<option value="2">3</option> 
</select><br> 

<div id="display">Select from the list to change this box</div> 
</body></html>
```